# Workflow wont trigger an E-Mail notification on current date

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, notifications

I have a workflow that is supposed to send an email when a date (Reminder Date) equals today's date. However, when the date comes up the workflow fails to trigger the workflow. What is missing?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Workflows only trigger either when an item is created, or when an item is changed.

You will either need to have a dummy field to enter any old text into to "trigger" the change, or you will need to use powershell to make it automatic (a bit tricky).

Comment: How would set this up in Sharepoint designer using the dummy field?

Comment: So have a field, called "change" (or whatever) and display it in a datasheet view, and then change it to something (like "1"), and then drag that box down like you would in excel to all the required items.

So because the item(s) have "changed" it will trigger the workflow. (As long as that workflow is set to trigger when changed). This is still a manual method, and may not be what you're after - so maybe a powershell option is the go.

This is how I archive big lists to other lists that I want to keep smaller.
I do this periodically (once every month, or so)